# Cordova connection plugin

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, plugman

I am creating phonegap project using cordova 3.4.0. I check the network connect is enable on while start the application. I installed cordova network-information plugin. The following codes are i am using.

```
if(navigator.network.connection.type == Connection.NONE){
    alert("nocon");
}else{
    alert("yescon");
}
```

It's working fine. But i want to display conform box for no network connection. One button for   settings and another one for cancel. If i click setting button, it will go to wifi-setting option. And if i click cancel button, app will exit. How can i do this. Please guide me.

Comment: I don't think you can access the native network settings tab cross platform without writing a plugin.

Comment: How can i write a new plugin. Can you give any example for that?

Answer (score 0):

on Click call the below function,

```
onclick="showConfirm();
```

and on js file add as below,

```
function showConfirm() {
        navigator.notification.confirm(
            'Your message here!',   // message
            onConfirm,              // callback to invoke with index of button pressed
            'Your title',           // title
            'Options,Exit'          // buttonLabels
        );
    }

function onConfirm(buttonIndex) {
        //Do the magic here.
    }
```

If you are satisfied with the answer then please click accept.